# Can't debug WCF service in visual studio 2013, can't start WcfSvcHost.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I have just created a WCF service library and wanted to test it. Pressed F5 in VS 2013 and got the following error.

```
Unable to start program 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7
\IDE\WcfSvcHost.exe.

The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running
on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote
computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.
```

Running VS 2013

Win 8.1

Firewall is Zone alarm.

Command Line arguments `/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"`

`Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution` is ticked

Comment: Try after disabling firewall OR add port to allowed in firewall.

Comment: I think the issue is related to having iis installed and iis express. I created a site in iis and put my service in the virtual folder. I browse to the service ok in IE so I added a console app project to the service solution and consumed the service I created in iis. Now when I press F5 to test the console app, VS launch's the service as well.

Comment: could you solve your problem?